# get Value of Disabled (Disabled & Selected previously) option in select box

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have written below lines to display multiselect box and I want to few option disabled which is previously selected.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name='cars[]'>
    <option value="volvo" disabled selected='selected'>Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

So here In POST method I want to get value of all the selected option including first one volvo.

Comment: Some browsers (all?) don't send disabled fields.  Either change it to readonly or get some really ugly JS hackery going :)

Comment: What do you mean by _previously selected_?

Comment: getting this problem in all browsers

Comment: Previously selected means, selected='selected' is set in option... Here What I need is I want to disallow user to un-select option which user has selected previously.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, no modern browser will submit a disabled option/field in a form. The easiest solution is to make it a "readonly" field by using the "readonly" attribute.

However, you will have to style the field to look like it has been disabled, as readonly does not change the field's appearance it just prevents the user from modifying it.

The ugly part is, however, that some browsers will NOT allow the readonly attribute to be set for a select field.

What I have usually done in this case is to actually disable the select and store the value in a hidden field instead using some not so ugly javascript to control this on the fly.

**Update:**

You could easily write a "serializeDisabled" function, iterating over the disabled form elements which have a name attribute and using the jQuery.param function at the end, to generate the serialized string (function comes from the user CMS here):

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.serializeDisabled = function () {
    var obj = {};

    $(':disabled[name]', this).each(function () { 
        obj[this.name] = $(this).val(); 
    });
    return $.param(obj);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a javascript function to loop around the options onSubmit and enabled them again. Disabled elements do not get posted.

Answer (score 1):

when you set the disabled never get in the POST data.... replace select to input type text..and use "readonly" property of that...

Thanks